# Error ([Errno 111] Connection refused) in veins (sumo-launchd.py)

Tags: python, omnet++, veins, sumo, mixim

i want to use [veins](http://veins.car2x.org/), to co-simulate between [OMNeT++](http://www.omnetpp.org/) network simulator and [SUMO](http://sumo-sim.org/) road traffic simulator.

Veins has [sumo-launchd](http://veins.car2x.org/documentation/sumo-launchd/) daemon (written in Python), that is designed to run in the background, listening for incoming requests. On each incoming connection, it receives the simulation setup in XML format, then launches a separate instance of SUMO and proxies requests between OMNeT++ and SUMO.

When i run [sumo-launchd.py](https://github.com/sommer/mixim-sommer/blob/veins/sumo-launchd.py) (after opening OMNet++ and start simulation) in the terminal, i get the following issue, which i believe is Python related.

```
bluemix@blueMix:~/SUMO/veins-2.1/examples/veins$ python /home/bluemix/SUMO/veins-2.1/sumo-launchd.py -vv -c /home/bluemix/SUMO/sumo-0.19.0/bin/sumo
Logging to /tmp/sumo-launchd.log
Listening on port 9999
Connection from 127.0.0.1 on port 45234
Handling connection from 127.0.0.1 on port 45234
Got TraCI message of length 2
Got TraCI command of length 1
Got TraCI command 0x0
Got CMD_GETVERSION
Got TraCI message of length 314
Got TraCI command of length 309
Got TraCI command 0x75
Got CMD_FILE_SEND for "sumo-launchd.launch.xml"
Got CMD_FILE_SEND with data "<launch>
  <copy file="erlangen.net.xml"/>
  <copy file="erlangen.rou.xml"/>
  <copy file="erlangen.poly.xml"/>
  <copy file="erlangen.sumo.cfg" type="config"/>
  <basedir path="/home/bluemix/OMNeTpp/omnetpp-4.3.1/samples/mixim/examples/veins/"/>
  <seed value="0"/>
</launch>
"
Creating temporary directory...
Temporary dir is /tmp/sumo-launchd-tmp-2JQTRd
Base dir is /home/bluemix/OMNeTpp/omnetpp-4.3.1/samples/mixim/examples/veins/
Seed is 0
Finding free port number...
Claiming lock on port
...found port 41320
Starting SUMO (/home/bluemix/SUMO/sumo-0.19.0/bin/sumo -c erlangen.sumo.cfg) on port 41320, seed 0
Connecting to SUMO (/home/bluemix/SUMO/sumo-0.19.0/bin/sumo -c erlangen.sumo.cfg) on port 41320 (try 1)
Error ([Errno 111] Connection refused)
Connecting to SUMO (/home/bluemix/SUMO/sumo-0.19.0/bin/sumo -c erlangen.sumo.cfg) on port 41320 (try 2)
Error ([Errno 111] Connection refused)
Connecting to SUMO (/home/bluemix/SUMO/sumo-0.19.0/bin/sumo -c erlangen.sumo.cfg) on port 41320 (try 3)
Error ([Errno 111] Connection refused)
Connecting to SUMO (/home/bluemix/SUMO/sumo-0.19.0/bin/sumo -c erlangen.sumo.cfg) on port 41320 (try 4)
Error ([Errno 111] Connection refused)
Connecting to SUMO (/home/bluemix/SUMO/sumo-0.19.0/bin/sumo -c erlangen.sumo.cfg) on port 41320 (try 5)
Error ([Errno 111] Connection refused)
Connecting to SUMO (/home/bluemix/SUMO/sumo-0.19.0/bin/sumo -c erlangen.sumo.cfg) on port 41320 (try 6)
Error ([Errno 111] Connection refused)
Connecting to SUMO (/home/bluemix/SUMO/sumo-0.19.0/bin/sumo -c erlangen.sumo.cfg) on port 41320 (try 7)
Error ([Errno 111] Connection refused)
Connecting to SUMO (/home/bluemix/SUMO/sumo-0.19.0/bin/sumo -c erlangen.sumo.cfg) on port 41320 (try 8)
Error ([Errno 111] Connection refused)
Connecting to SUMO (/home/bluemix/SUMO/sumo-0.19.0/bin/sumo -c erlangen.sumo.cfg) on port 41320 (try 9)
Error ([Errno 111] Connection refused)
Connecting to SUMO (/home/bluemix/SUMO/sumo-0.19.0/bin/sumo -c erlangen.sumo.cfg) on port 41320 (try 10)
Error ([Errno 111] Connection refused)
Releasing lock on port
Cleaning up
Result: "<?xml version="1.0"?>
<status>
    <exit-code>-1</exit-code>
    <start>1390404178</start>
    <end>1390404189</end>
    <status>Could not connect to SUMO ([Errno 111] Connection refused). Might be protected by a personal firewall or crashed before a connection could be established.</status>
    <stdout><![CDATA[Loading configuration... done.
]]></stdout>
    <stderr><![CDATA[Error: Empty edges in roundabout.
Quitting (on error).
]]></stderr>
</status>
"
Closing connection from 127.0.0.1 on port 45234
^CKeyboard interrupt.
Shutting down.
```

and the information from OMNeT++ console:

```
<!> Error in module (TraCIScenarioManagerLaunchd) scenario.manager (id=6) at event #1, t=0: Model error: Connection to TraCI server lost. Check your server's log. Error message: 104: Connection reset by peer.

TRAPPING on the exception above, due to a debug-on-errors=true configuration option. Is your debugger ready?

Simulation terminated with exit code: 2
```

I googled ([1](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/omnetpp/05iHVFNhiYs), [2](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/omnetpp/QX0SL67lJ-0)) the problem, but not exactly the same as mine.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the reply from the veins owner ([Christoph Sommer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4707703/christoph-sommer)):

> https://github.com/sommer/mixim-sommer/archive/b47beb0c.zip
>
> This one should work for all current versions of SUMO. Note that it
>   has not received extensive testing yet, so please let me know any
>   problems.
>
> Best,
>
> Christoph

You can check this [link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/omnetpp/7QL2k6QfQqw) to see the talk.

Answer (score 0):

you need to launch the sumo by using the following line from terminal:

```
sumo-launchd.py -vv -c sumo-gui
```

and the run the `omnetpp.ini` file from `omnet++`

Comment: sumo or sumo-gui have the same results. The best answer i get is from Veins developer (Sommer), as i showed in my own answer.